# MYSQL Between Date not working

Tags: mysql, date, between

I am using CodeIgnitor, and below is my query.

```
$query = $this->db->query('
SELECT * FROM `dbname`.`sales` 
WHERE product_id='.$id.' 
AND date BETWEEN 2015-07-01 AND 2015-07-31
');
```

It is saying it is retrieving 0 rows, but I know for a fact they exist. 
What is wrong with my query?

Comment: Sorry this is my first question on StackOverflow. I didn't see how to embed code

Comment: You can edit your question and fix the indent. Have a look at [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for help about formatting your code.

Comment: Where is the edit button? I don't see it anywhere?

Comment: I figured it out, it should be <code>$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM `dbname`.`sales` WHERE product_id='.$id.' AND date BETWEEN "2015-07-18 00:00:00" AND "2015-07-31 00:00:00"');</code>

Comment: actually, you just need quote for your date

Comment: sorry guys i can't figure out how to post code or use tags on here

Comment: Just indent the code with four spaces. There should be an edit button right below your question's tags.